Change language in a <v-naigation-drawer>. It renders only once
I am using vue-i18n t(text-tag) to change language in my application. I have it working for all the pages except the navigation-drawer because the nav-drawer does not re-render.
   <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" temporary>
      <drawer-component />
    </v-navigation-drawer>


I want to change the language on the menu items in the nav-drawer.
I the drawer-component, I have the language being set during render by using

tried both ref and let, both don't work

in DrawerComponent.vue
import { watch, ref } from 'vue'
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

const { t, locale } = useI18n()

const menuhome = ref(t('$vuetify.menuhome'))
let menuabout = t('$vuetify.menuabout')
let menudocuments = t('$vuetify.menudocuments')

/** Drawer menu items */
const items: DrawerMenuItem[] = [
  {
    title: menuhome.value,
    icon: 'mdi-home',
    to: { name: 'Home' }
  },
  {
    title: '-' // Divider
  },
  {
    title: menuabout,
    icon: 'mdi-information',
    to: { name: 'About' },
  },
  {
    title: menudocuments,
    icon: 'mdi-file-document-multiple-outline',
    to: {name: 'Documents' },
  },
}
</script>
<template>
  <v-list nav>
    <template v-for="item in items" :key="item.title">
      <v-divider v-if="item.title === '-'" />
      <template v-else>
        <!-- Menu Item -->
        <v-list-item
          v-if="!item.items"
          :disabled="!item.to"
          :prepend-icon="item.icon"
          :title="item.title"
          :to="item.to"
          link
        />
     </template>
  </template>
 </v-list>
</template>
 

I have a store that I change when the language changes.
I want to re-render the the DrawerComponent.
It there away to send a event to a component from a store?

I am now getting an event from changing the language and changing the values but because "items" is not a ref, it is not changing to title in the nav-bar

I put a computed around the items data and it is changing it now. but I am getting an error on items.
Type 'ComputedRef<({ title: string; icon: string; to: { name: string; }; } | { title: string; icon?: undefined; to?: undefined; })[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'DrawerMenuItem[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.ts-plugin(2740)

because it's no longer DrawerMenuItem[], it's now a computed property containing that type, so const items = computed<DrawerMenuItem[]> is how you could type it.

Thanks, I found that out yesterday
